# Using mail-listener2 to read emails from Hoodiecrow

Tags: node.js, protractor

I use **Hoodiecrow** (http://hoodiecrow.com/) as an IMAP server and **mail-listener2** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mail-listener2) as a IMAP client. Both are npm modules.

I am trying to retrieve messages from Hoodiecrow using the mail-listener2 client.

Here is my mail-listener2 configuration:

```
var MailListener = require('mail-listener2');

// here goes your email connection configuration
var mailListener = new MailListener({
    username: 'testuser',
    password: 'testpass',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 1143, // imap port
    tls: false,
    tlsOptions: {rejectUnauthorized: true},
    mailbox: 'INBOX', // mailbox to monitor
    searchFilter: ['UNSEEN'], // the search filter being used after an IDLE notification has been retrieved
    markSeen: true, // all fetched email willbe marked as seen and not fetched next time
    fetchUnreadOnStart: true, // use it only if you want to get all unread email on lib start. Default is `false`,
    mailParserOptions: {streamAttachments: true}, // options to be passed to mailParser lib.
    attachments: true, // download attachments as they are encountered to the project directory
    attachmentOptions: {directory: 'attachments/'} // specify a download directory for attachments
});

mailListener.start();

mailListener.on("server:connected", function () {
    console.log("Mail listener initialized");
});



var getLastEmail = function () {
    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
    console.log("Waiting for an email...");

    mailListener.on("mail", function (mail) {
        deferred.fulfill(mail);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};

global.mailListener = mailListener;
global.getLastEmail = getLastEmail;
```

However, I am not sure how to configure my application to use the Hoodiecrow IMAP server.

Can someone please help?